# What is the time complexity of a linked list?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

Suppose you want to insert n elements into an empty linked list while maintaining the sorted order.What is the worst case time?

Comment: That's basically the example used in most text books to explain different complexities, so maybe you need to read some of those? Also, since this is obviously homework, please demonstrate at least an effort on your side!

Comment: Its not homework actually, I'm a graduate and recently taking interest in computer science.

Answer (score 1):

If, by "maintaining the sorted order", you mean they're coming in already sorted, it's an `O(n)` operation as you simply tack each of them on the end of the list (and you can keep a record of the current end rather than searching for it each time):

```
make new list from first value, keeping pointer to last, O(1)
for curr in second and subsequent values, O(n):
    add to list using last, update last, O(1)
```

If you instead mean they're *not* sorted but they *should* be, that would be `O(n2)`, as *each* of the `n` new values will result in an `O(n)` search followed by an `O(1)` insert:

```
for curr in values, O(n):
    find insertion point, O(n)
    insert at that point, O(1)
```

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, but why does o(n) for search and o(1) for insertion results in an o(n^2) in total complexity?

Comment: @RafiLushan: you need *never* apologise for seeking knowledge or clarity :-) It's because you need to do that `O(n)+O(1) == O(n)` for *each* of the `n` things you want to insert: sort of like `O(n)` occurrences of a thing that's *already* `O(n)` is `O(n*n)`.

Comment: @RafiLushan: think of it like the bubble-sort. A single pass of the entire `n` elements (that single pass being `O(n)` since you have to go through every element for the pass) will put *one* of those elements in its final correct position. But you need to do that `n` times, one for each element. Hence `O(n*n)`. Nested loops, with all levels based on the input size, always give you some power of `n` in the complexity analysis.

Answer (score 0):

if your doing sorting after every new insertion of an element then the worst-case time complexity will be o(n^2). (Insertion will take o(1) then sorting will take o(n^2).)

or if your inserting all your element at once then apply the sorting then it would take o(nlogn).(with merge sort)